# JFrame theme and appearance

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

I have a swing application. Below is a small screenshot.
[image]

OS: Win 7

What is irritating is the theme. I have tried several other screens but they all have such appearance. Eclipse and Netbeans for example have a much better UI. The FileChooser and Frame is general is much pleasing. How do I have such a theme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change the look and feel to the Windows one before creating anything UI-related in your program:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Comment: Make sure you put it BEFORE you create the JFrame. I have made this mistake many times.

Comment: @Ajay you can call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame)` if the frame is already created.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using the Metal Look and Feel. Try using some other look and feel that might interest you.

Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html, for more information.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you everything you want to know

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

`UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` will give you the most appropriate for the OS it's running on

Answer (score 3):

there is many look and feels packages like :

> 1)JTattoo
>
> 2)BlueLight
>
> 3)joxy
>
> 4)Nimrod
>
> 5)Oyoaha
>
> 6)TinyLaf

....etc

you have to read about previous types